# Call C# codebehind function, when I clicked the button the div will show

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net

How do I call `Button1_Click` when a user clicked the button `Button1`?

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "id", "show(showdivslowly)", true);
}


<!-- language: lang-html -->
<div id="showdivslowly" runat="server" style="width: 500px; height: 200px; background-color: Blue; display: none">Welcome</div>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button1_Click" />
```

Comment: and it does not at the moment?

Comment: What you have at the moment is a bit daft. It will do a postback to the server which will then process the server side click event and send javascript to the browser which when the response returns will run the javascript. You probably want something like `OnClientClick="show(showdivslowly)"` so as to avoid the request/response roundtrip.

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string script = "show(showdivslowly);";
   ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "Show", script, true);
}
```

use RegisterClientScriptBlock instead of  RegisterStartupScript method.